# How do I go about unit testing view models in the MVVM-Light framework?

Tags: unit-testing, mvvm, tdd, mvvm-light

My specific question is when the viewmodel constructor is modeled after the MVVM-Light examples, like this one

```
    public MainViewModel()
{
    if (IsInDesignMode)
    {
        BackgroundBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
    }
    else
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<Brush>(
            this, 
            true, 
            m => BackgroundBrush = m);

        ShutdownCommand
            = new RelayCommand(ShutdownService.RequestShutdown);
    }
}
```

Should test this? What should I test?  Looks like I should test if the class is registered to listen for a message, and if it wires up a ShutdownCommand.  My current issue is that ShutdownCommand is setup and calls what it is supposed to call.  I also don't quite get TDD yet, so maybe I'm just asking all the wrong questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can test the behaviour of your MainViewModel when a Brush message is received.
You can also test that ShutdownCommand is not null.
Unit testing is about testing the public states, behaviors, and interactions of your objects.
If you simply set a private field in your constructor, what is there to test?
Don't bother unit-testing your simple accessors and mutators. That's just silly, and it doesn't help anyone.